# Why can't I upload files with PHP?

Tags: php

I'm having trouble getting PHP file uploads to work on a CentOS server.  Here is a very basic version of the script.  It shows no errors, but the uploaded file doesn't exist in /tmp.

```
<?php
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_FILES);
  echo "</pre>";            
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"/tmp/uploaded");
?>

<html>
   <body>
      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="image" />
         <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

`/tmp` is owned by root with permissions drwxrwxrwt.  SELinux is permissive.  I verified apache user can write here with `sudo -u apache touch /tmp/asdf`

`upload_tmp_dir` is not defined in php.ini so I expect it to be using the system default `/tmp`.  I verified this with `sys_get_temp_dir()`.

The `$_FILES` variable looks good:

```
Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => antergos.jpeg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpqhhhxL
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 924202
        )

)
```

I tried adding a `sleep(10)` so I can have time to check before the script finishes, and it's not writing anything to `/tmp`.

Comment: Which file does not exists? `/tmp/phpqhhhxL` or `/tmp/uploaded`

Comment: why are you storing your file in `tmp/` folder ? use or create a new folder but not in `tmp` folder

Comment: Neither file exists.  For my real application I will place the files somewhere else, this is just to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Why is this question getting downvotes?

Comment: Try `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"./uploads/$uniquefilename");` But first create the `uploads` folder under your DocumentRoot

Comment: @ElliottB check my answer.

Comment: I figured out that it doesn't like absolute paths. But it will work if I use a relative path, even if I go up many levels.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define upload_tmp_dir in php.ini otherwise it will not work.

Comment: I tried setting this to /tmp but it still doesn't work.  But I shouldn't have to set this.  See http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir

Comment: This is what I have for my virtualhost and it works on debian
`php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/temp"`